# Use USB Barcode Scanner as Serial Device

Tags: usb, scanner, serial, com, barcode

I have an USB barcode scanner that is recognized as Keyboard. I have to read the scanned barcodes in background using Java but it seems to be no way to read directly from an USB port (and I do not want to create a general keylogger).
My idea was to install a driver that allows me to see the device as Serial, so I can read from the COM Stream.
I Googled a lot and installed already several drivers but I cannot understand how to accomplish the target.
My dev machine is on Windows and the Prod Env will be on Linux, so I should find a way to do it in both OS.
Any suggestion?
Thanks

Comment: Each of these devices is independent... I am going to flag this for closure as it's a development question, but basically you WANT this as a keyboard in almost all cases... Click the spot for the barcode to go and scan, just enters the text in the field, this is the most common usage case so it's how most scanners are designed. If you need a different application you may need to go back to the OEM and persue a DCR (Design Change Request) that is specific to your application.

Comment: Apart from the dev problem, the question is "Is there a way to map a generic USB device on a Virtual COM port?"

Comment: I can't answer the question for Windows, but on Linux the barcode scanner should show up as a `/dev/tty*` device automatically, so you don't really need to do anything - just open the file (ideally use a command line argument to your Java program for the path) and read the digits from it. No "keylogger" needed. Edit your question with the additional lines in `dmesg` after you plug it into the Linux box if you want us to verify this.

Comment: *"seems to be no way to read directly from an USB port"* --  USB is a bus and not a device, so it's the job of the OS to handle bus packets.  Would you try to *"read directly"* PCIe?  *"My idea was to install a driver that allows me to see the device as Serial"* -- The USB device (that you plug in) sends identification information to the host; that info is used to install a driver for the device.  That device info is in the system log that @dirkt requested.